# How to resolve AAPT2 error?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0, aapt2

I am working on authentication through firebase since when I added `implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.0'` I am getting `AAPT2 error: check logs for details` error after syncing the gradle.
Here are my build.gradle files.

build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
repositories {
mavenLocal()
flatDir {
    dirs 'libs'
}
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

implementation 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'


//  Firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'

implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'

// Displaying images
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And build.gradle(Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1' // google-services 
plugin



    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
    }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The moment I delete this `implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.0'` the error is gone. I think adding this is creating `AAPT2 error`.

`Google SDK Tools`, `Google Repository` and `Google Play Services` are also installed. Please also explain what is this `AAPT2 error` and how this occur if possible.

Comment: Run **assembleDebug** in gradle console to find the specific line causing the error.

Comment: @Abhi check out the edited version of the problem. I've there mentioned the line which is causing error.

Comment: Did assembleDebug give that line as the cause of error? There might be other conflicting error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.3'
```

Instead of this

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
```

> Update `compileSdkVersion 27` and `targetSdkVersion 27`

Comment: @a_petrolhead Open the `gradle.properties` and add this:

`android.enableAapt2=false`

Comment: @a_petrolhead test case try to update `compileSdkVersion 27` and `targetSdkVersion 27`

Comment: @a_petrolhead may you can try that

Comment: When I comment this `implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.0' ` out then after syncing gradle I am not getting any errors. So, I dont think changing sdk version would help.
`

Comment: Updating compilesdkversion and targetsdkversion to 27 worked. I think as I am using latest versions of FirebaseDatabase and Firebase authentication dependencies that is why it is necessary to update sdk versions to the latest. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio Aapt2 is enabled by default when you use android plugin for gradle 3.0.

This is primarily done to improve the incremental resource processing, check [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0.html) page for more info.

If you don't want to see this error you can disable it by adding the the following lines in your gradle.properties.

android.enableAapt2=false

Comment: This is not a fix, just a workaround and it is probably deprecated by now.

Answer (score 0):

***Solved!!*** The problem is with versioning.

> **your app's build.gradle must also be updated to specify a compileSdkVersion of at least 26 (Android O)**

Took me couple of hours to figure out.

Read more here, https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/08/some-updates-to-apps-using-google-play.html